# What is difference between `ng lint --format=stylish` and `ng lint` in Angular

Tags: angular, lint

I was going through `ng lint` command and also checked `ng lint --help` but I was unable to find any difference between `ng lint --format=prose` and `ng lint --format=stylish` . I could not find any documentation for the same.Please help me. Can anyone give link to proper documentation for the same.

Answer (score 4):

In tslint, you have a few formats [available](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/formatters/).

Those formatters are used to format the output of tslint. Prose is the simple human-readable output, and stylish is another human readable output.

Comment: Both appear same.

Comment: Maybe there's a bug : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11005